# Best practice on data access with remote cluster: pushing from client memory to workers vs direct link from worker to data storage

Tags: dask

Hi I am new to dask and cannot seem to find relevant examples on the topic of this title. Would appreciate any documentation or help on this.

The example I am working with is pre-processing of an image dataset on the azure environment with the dask_cloudprovider library, I would like to increase the speed of processing by dividing the work on a cluster of machines.

From what I have read and tested, I can
(1) load the data to memory on the client machine, and push it to the workers or

```
'''psudo code
load data into array and send it to workers through delayed func'''
```

(2) I can establish a link between every worker node and the data storage (see func below), and access the data on the worker level.

```
'''def get_remote_image(img_path):
ACCOUNT_NAME = 'xxx'
ACCOUNT_KEY = 'xxx'
CONTAINER = 'xxx'

abfs = adlfs.AzureBlobFileSystem(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=ACCOUNT_KEY, container_name=CONTAINER)
file = abfs.cat(img_path)
image = imageio.core.asarray(imageio.imread(file, "PNG"))
return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)'''
```

What I would like to know more about is whether there are any best practices on accessing and working on data on a remote cluster using dask?

Comment: I don't work in the cloud, but option 2 sounds more efficient (or if the data is very large then option 1 might not be feasible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to try version 1), you would first see warnings saying that sending large delayed objects is a bad pattern in Dask, and makes for large graphs and high memory use on the scheduler. You *can* send the data directly to workers using `client.scatter`, but it would still be essentially a serial process, bottlenecking on receiving and sending all of your data through the client process's network connection.

The best practice and canonical way to load data in Dask is for the workers to do it. All the built in loading functions work this way, and is even true when running locally (because any download or open logic should be easily parallelisable).

This is also true for the *outputs* of your processing. You haven't said what you plan to do next, but to grab all of those images to the client (e.g., `.compute()`) would be the other side of exactly the same bottleneck. You want to reduce and/or write your images directly on the workers and only handle small transfers from the client.

Note that there are examples out there of image processing with dask (e.g., https://examples.dask.org/applications/image-processing.html ) and of course a lot about arrays. Passing around whole image arrays might be fine for you, but this should be worth a read.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the file system and open files are pickleable, so you can probably use `fsspec` functions in the client to make things simpler.